# "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2" when passing a useState function in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-state

I have a component which passes a useState setter to a utility function:

```
export interface IData {
  editable: string[];
  favourited: string[];
}

const [data, setData] = useState<IData | undefined>(undefined)

useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      fetchUserDoc(session?.user?.uid, setData);
    }
  }, [status]);
```

The utility function gets a document from Firestore and passes the document data to the setter. If the document doesn't exist, it creates the document and then calls itself to redo the process.

```
export interface IFetchDocProps {
  uid: string;
  setData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<DocumentData>>;
}

export default async function fetchUserDoc({
  uid,
  setData,
}: IFetchDocProps) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    let data = docSnap.data();
    setData(data);
  } else {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
      editable: [],
      favourited: [],
    });
    fetchUserDoc(uid, setData);
  }
}
```

When `fetchUserDoc(uid, setData)` is called it gives the error `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)`.

Any pointers? I think I may have confused the interfaces somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function fetchUserDoc only has 1 parameter which is

```
{
  uid,
  setData,
}: IFetchDocProps
```

is is an interface with to fields/attributes inside but in therms of function parameter it is only one.

And when you are calling the function you are passing 2 parameters:

```
fetchUserDoc(uid, setData);
```

uid     -> Pram1
setData -> Para2

To fix this you will have to instantiate one object with to attributes inside and pass it as a single parameter:

```
//pseudocode!!
//Initialize argument object passing two fields it has 
let param = new IFetchDocProps( uid, setData )
// call the function passing a single parameter
fetchUserDoc( param )
```

Those are **Pseudocodes** just get the idea...

Comment: thanks for the concise explanation! makes a lot of sense, not sure how I overlooked this haha

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, your function is expecting a single argument as an object, so you should call it like;

```
fetchUserDoc({uid, setData});
```